# How to change imageview shape to round on menu item selected in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to `android` and now I am stuck at one point.
i want to change shape of `imageview` when user `click` on menu item Circle.

my **circle_shape.xml** file in `drawable` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#FF44FF"/>
</shape>
```

my java File **Shape.java**

```
package com.example.mixapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Shape_with_Spinner extends Activity {

    Spinner shapeSpinner;
    ImageView imgMaster;
    private Drawable drawable;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shape_with__spinner);
        try {
            imgMaster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMaster);
            Toast.makeText(this, "in try part ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Magaj jay che have", ""+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this, "in catch part : "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.rect:
            drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_shape);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
}
```

and my **Shape.xml** file in layout folder.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mixapp.Shape_with_Spinner" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/shapeSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:entries="@array/Spinner_value"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgToShape"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

any help would be appreciable. :)

Comment: maybe you just need `imgMaster.setImageDrawable(drawable)` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt let me try it now. (y)

Comment: @Blackbelt not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for it. This libs not only allowed you to async load images, but you could also set up the transformations(here is ready to use circle transformations [Picasso](https://gist.github.com/julianshen/5829333), [Glide](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations)) for any image that should be loaded.

Comment: I've gone through the links that you've provided, but tomorrow i have exam and such libs wont be there, so is there any way to make it simple by some traditional way, and is it of Android studio? I'm having eclipse right now.

Comment: @devin_child you could try to use this source code https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView/blob/master/roundedimageview/src/main/java/com/makeramen/roundedimageview/RoundedDrawable.java

Comment: I did it by creating another XML file for shape and in java, set it by the setImageDrawable(<ShapeDrawable object>);